# How to use NuGet-Packages with svn?

Tags: c#, svn, nuget-package

In my project there are some NuGet-Packages installed. The packages.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr3.Runtime" version="3.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="FluentNHibernate" version="2.1.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="4.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

I commited my project and updated it on another location (same computer). But now I get the following errors when I try to build the project:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OnlineApplicationMapping, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "FluentNHibernate, Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Iesi.Collections, Version=4.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
1>C:\branches\Version\OnlineApplicationMapping\Mapping\ONLINE_ANTRAG_TYPMap.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FluentNHibernate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>C:\branches\Version\OnlineApplicationMapping\Mapping\ONLINE_BEFUELL_MAPMap.cs(1,7,1,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FluentNHibernate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>C:\branches\Version\OnlineApplicationMapping\Mapping\ONLINE_ANTRAG_TYPMap.cs(11,34,11,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClassMap<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>C:\branches\Version\OnlineApplicationMapping\Mapping\ONLINE_BEFUELL_MAPMap.cs(11,35,11,63): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClassMap<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It seems like, the dlls from the NuGet-Packages are missing.

Do I really have to put the dlls in the repository? Isn't NuGet supposed to get the files from some server in this case?

Comment: Right click the project and click "Restore Nuget packages"

Comment: How to make Visual Studio automatically restore missing packages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting

Comment: @Austin T French: There is only a "Restore Nuget packages" when I click at the solution (not the project). And when I choos this the follwoing output comes: "All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore."

Comment: You should be OK then... Maybe just a plain clean / rebuild. Maybe a reboot. Otherwise look at Nuget and confirm the right versions are where they should be...

Comment: Having once had a "Head of" who was very suspicious about nuget, we downloaded the packages to a local repository, which we included in our git repo. The same should be possible with svn. You simply load from the local nuget repo instead of the online one. Drawback: you need to manually update the local nuget repo if you want latest packages. Pro: Makes you somewhat resilient to network outages or libs "disappearing" from nuget (which I never had a problem with but it was the argument made by our "head of"). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds

Comment: @felix-b: I tried the things from your link (Chapter: "Other potential conditions"). Means I deleted the "Packages" Folder, downloaded the latest NuGet.exe from here: https://www.nuget.org/downloads and called "nuget locals all -clear" from the command line. The result is, that Visual Studio throws an exception when I try to use "Restore Nuget packages". So Im not able to build this solution anymore :-(

Comment: ok, after a restart of VS, it finally worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. I finally got this with the help of Austin T French and felix-b (see comments). I tried to follow the orders from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting Chapter: "Other potential conditions"

This is what I did:

- I closed Visual Studio
- I deleted the "Packages" Folder (in the solution-folder)
- I downloaded the latest NuGet.exe from here: https://www.nuget.org/downloads
- I called "nuget locals all -clear" from the command line.
- I reopend Visual Studio
- I right-clicked on the solution (in VS) and chose: "Restore Nuget packages"
- I rebuilded the solution